# How to set Attributes in Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I need to set the "People" attribute in firebase. I don't know how to set dictionary attribute using SWIFT.
 I have added my code below which I have tried .

```
let key = snapshot.key

        let upload = ["id":key,
                  "status":status,] as [String : Any]

        databaseRef.child("location").child(key).setValue(upload)
```

[This image is firebase data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjjPP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  let key = snapshot.key

  let updates: [String: Any] = [
     "/id": key,
     "/people/name1": <yourValue>,
     "/people/name2": <yourValue>,
     "/status": status
  ]

  databaseRef.child("location").child(key).updateChildValues(updates)
```

Hope it helps